# method is not a function on a given object that extends another object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, extends

Consider the following:

```
// some_object_name.js
var SomeOtherObject = require('./some_other_object');

var SomeObjectName = _.extend({}, SomeOtherObject);

module.exports = SomeObjectName;
```

Now consider the following:

```
// some_other_object.js
var SomeOtherObject = {
   method: function() {
       console.log('something');
   }
}

module.exports = SomeOtherObject;
```

Run this through browserify with babelify and then run `SomeObjectName.method()` and you get:

> Uncaught TypeError: SomeObjectName.method is not a function

**um .... what?**

If I understand `_.extend` then I should have access to all of `SomeOtherObject`'s methods

Comment: What's the code being output by browserify?

Comment: So something somewhere is requiring `some_object_name` right?

Comment: The code you've posted runs fine so it's probably a problem that exists in the code you're obfuscating or in the browserify/babelify stack which people are unlikely to install so you should probably post the output